# Underscore templating: Can't get switch to work

Tags: underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I can't get a simple switch statement working in my underscore template. It's using the value of a variable called UserType which I've checked exists by displaying it with <%= UserType %>.

Code coming up:

```
<% switch(UserType) { %>
    <% case 13: %>
        <button id="schoolButton" value="schools" class="gridChooser k-textbox">Schools</button> 
    <% case 12: %>
        <button id="teacherButton" value="teachers" class="gridChooser k-textbox">Teacher</button> 
    <% case 8: %>
        <button id="classButton" value="classes" class="gridChooser k-textbox">Classes</button> 
        <button id="testButton" value="tests" class="gridChooser k-textbox">Test</button> 
<% } %>
```

Any help much appreciated - thanks.

Answer (score 24):

The problem is that Underscore will add semicolon terminators when converting your template to JavaScript. So, a simple `switch` like this:

```
<% switch(x) { %>
<% case 11: %>
    <button>
<% } %>
```

becomes JavaScript that looks like this:

```
switch(x) { ;
case 11: ;
    // something to output '<button>' goes here
} ;
```

But a JavaScript [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) needs to contain `case` statements and an empty statement (i.e. the `;` in `switch(x) { ;`) doesn't qualify.

I can't think of any sane way around this problem so I'd just switch to an `if` and move on to more interesting problems:

```
<% if(UserType === 13) { %>
    <button id="schoolButton" value="schools" class="gridChooser k-textbox">Schools</button> 
<% } else if(UserType === 12) { %>
    <button id="teacherButton" value="teachers" class="gridChooser k-textbox">Teacher</button> 
<% } else if(UserType === 8) { %>
    <button id="classButton" value="classes" class="gridChooser k-textbox">Classes</button> 
    <button id="testButton" value="tests" class="gridChooser k-textbox">Test</button> 
<% } %>
```

You could also turn it inside-out and use `print`:

```
<% switch(UserType) {
   case 13:
       print('<button id="schoolButton" ...');
   ...
} %>
```

but that's a bit ugly (IMHO). See the [`_.template` documentation](http://underscorejs.org/#template) for details.

---

Note that this semicolon trickery is also why your `if`s must include braces in an Underscore template even if JavaScript doesn't require them. So this won't work:

```
<% if(pancakes) %>
    <%= pancakes %>
```

but this will:

```
<% if(pancakes) { %>
    <%= pancakes %>
<% } %>
```

The same applies to loops.

Comment: Wonderful answer. Thanks for explaining why the expected solution doesn't work.

Comment: @DanM: Thanks. I had to go digging around in the compiled version of the template so I figured I should share what I found: if I can't explain it then I don't understand it, if I don't understand it then I don't feel right answering.

Answer (score 13):

You can do:

```
<% switch(UserType) { case 13: %>
  <button id="schoolButton" value="schools" class="gridChooser k-textbox">Schools</button> 
  <% break; case 12: %>
  <button id="teacherButton" value="teachers" class="gridChooser k-textbox">Teacher</button> 
  <% break; case 8: %>
  <button id="classButton" value="classes" class="gridChooser k-textbox">Classes</button> 
  <button id="testButton" value="tests" class="gridChooser k-textbox">Test</button> 
<% break; } %>
```

It isn't a "comfortable" solution, but neither is wrong. Just works.