# Using callback function with loop in underscore.js of backbone.js project not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am developing `backbone.js` project with `underscore.js` and `require.js`.

I created a javascript callback function in order to get data from web service using `ajax` :

```
this.getProCallBack = function(type,callback){
var result = "";
  $.ajax({
    url: url, //rest url
    type:"GET", 
    dataType:"json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(response){
        result = callback(response);
    }
  });
}
```

Here is **View** of backbone.js

```
 define(["jquery" ,
   "underscore" ,
   "backbone",
   "text!templates/Layout/ba.html",
   "promo"
 ],function($, _, Backbone, BannerTem, Promo){
    var BaView = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize : function(){
        },
        render: function(options){
           var _banner = _.template(BannerTem);
           $(this.el).html(_banner({type : this.options.type}));
           return this;
       }
     });
     return BannerView;
 });
```

I'm using `text.js` of to call underscore template with html file.

Here is a template :  **ba.html**

```
<div id="ei-slider" class="ei-slider">
 <ul class="ei-slider-large">
    <%
        var home = new Promo();
        home.getProCallBack(type,function(result){
        _.each(result, function(slideimg){
            switch(slideimg.ItemCount){
                case 0 :
                alert(slideimg.PromotionImage);
    %>
    <li>
        <a href="#detail/<%=slideimg.ItemList[0].UID%>">
            <img src="slideimg.PromotionImage%>" />
        </a>
    </li>
    <%
            break;
            default:
    %>
    <li>
        <a href="#detail" style="float: left;">
            <img src="slideimg.PromotionImage%>" />
        </a>
    </li>
    <%
        }
    %>
 </ul>
</div>
```

**Problem** : `alert()` is working in `case` block, yet `<img>` did not show in `DOM`.

I'm not sure is it because of `_.each()` does not work in `callback` function or what could be caused this problem.

Any idea what could be causing this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is a bit backwards. AJAX calls don't work that well inside templates because of timing issues.

You should turn your logic inside out so that the AJAX call is in your view and you handle the template inside the `$.ajax` success callback. Something like this in your view:

```
render: function(options){
    var _banner = _.template(BannerTem);
    var home    = new Promo();
    home.getProCallBack(this.options.type, function(result) {
        this.$el.html(_banner({result result}));
    }.bind(this));
    return this;
}
```

and then the template would be more like this:

```
<div id="ei-slider" class="ei-slider">
    <ul class="ei-slider-large">
        <% _.each(result, function(slideimg) {
            if(slideimg.ItemCount == 0) { %>
                <li>
                    <a href="#detail/<%=slideimg.ItemList[0].UID%>">
                        <img src="<%= slideimg.PromotionImage%>" />
                    </a>
                </li>
            <% } else { %>
                <li>
                    <a href="#detail" style="float: left;">
                        <img src="<%= slideimg.PromotionImage%>" />
                    </a>
                </li>
            <% }
        }) %>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I switch the `switch` to an `if/else` along the way, a [`switch` is difficult to get right in an Underscore template](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15951255/479863) so I tend not to bother.

Comment: But what if I have more than one callback functions to use in html template? How to pass more than one result by calling callback function from view to template?

Comment: You'd probably use several `$.ajax` calls and a promise to trigger a callback when they're all done.

Comment: I tried : `$.when(
 home.getProCallBack(this.options.type, function(_result) {
  this.topDep = _result;
 })
).then(function() {
 console.log(this.topDep);
 this.$el.html(_banner({result : this.topDep}));
}.bind(this));` but `this.topDep` is undefined.